# how to define the k-hop parameter and number of gcn layers when establishing a gcn network?

Tags: pytorch, difference

how to define the k-hop parameter and number of gcn layers when establishing a gcn network? what is the difference of these two parameters, are they the same thing?
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thank you

I am searching for a long time on net including github and bing search, however, no specific answer
I wanner know the difference between k-hop and gcn layers, are they the same or where is the difference?